# Openapi Generator Minimum Maximum Range integer Go

Tags: go, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I have a go project using the [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech) with `openapi: "3.0.3"`.

I am attempting to implement error validation using a `minimum` and `maximum` range for an int64 request body variable.  I would think that this type of validation could happen within the generated controllers.  For example, somewhere like the [AssertPetRequired example](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/11d29eb22b1e3ce75c6969adf32e565a259114f6/samples/server/petstore/go-chi-server/go/model_pet.go#L31-L51).  I looked through the [controller-api.mustache file](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/1cdcaeb1b9dd10730b01bcb87b8df2d89d3a8499/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/go-server/controller-api.mustache) and do not see anything helpful.  My post request body looks like the following (I’ve tried every combination I can think of for: [minimum, maximum, exclusiveMinimum and exclusiveMaximum](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#schema-object).

```
requestBody:
    required: true
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          type: object           
          properties:
            id:
              type: string
            amount:
              type: integer
              format: int64
              minimum: 1
              exclusiveMinimum: true
              maximum: 10
              exclusiveMaximum: true
            label:
              type: string
          required:
            - id
            - amount
```

Is there some additional library that I need to add or am I missing something basic within my `yaml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are generating a [go server](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/go-server/), not a [go client](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/go/).

Unfortunately, the go server generators don't support validations yet. But this feature is [planned](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/15185) for the 7.0.0 release, which is scheduled for June 2023.

Comment: thanks @gebi.  Yes, I'm using this for a go server and not a client as you pointed out.  Thanks for the link.  I'll mark this answer as correct.